How to share grpc channel between code-first grpc clients?
I have a microservice with 20+ code-first grpc services. For now I create code-first clients like this:
serviceCollection.AddCodeFirstGrpcClient<IMyService1>(o => {
    o.Address = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:5011");
    o.InterceptorRegistrations.Add(...);
    o.ChannelOptionsActions.Add(...);
});

serviceCollection.AddCodeFirstGrpcClient<IMyService2>(o => {
    o.Address = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:5011");
    o.InterceptorRegistrations.Add(...);
    o.ChannelOptionsActions.Add(...);
});

serviceCollection.AddCodeFirstGrpcClient<IMyService3>(o => {
    o.Address = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:5011");
    o.InterceptorRegistrations.Add(...);
    o.ChannelOptionsActions.Add(...);
});

// And so on

However I assume it would be better to have single channel (allowing multiple HTTP2 connections) shared by all clients (that connect to same address and have same configuration / interceptors).
I can't find a way to share a channel between multiple code-first clients.
I can imagine that I could add shared grpc channel like this for example:
// Keyed because I assume that there will be more services on different ports
serviceCollection.AddKeyedSingleton("http://127.0.0.1:5011", (IServiceProvider services) => {
   return GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://127.0.0.1:5011");
})

But how I can configure code-first client to use this channel?
